# Recorded VBA code fails in Word

Tags: vba, google-docs, ms-word, word-2010

In Word 2010 one can import text from another file by `choosing Object-> Text from File..` on the `Insert tab`. This works fine for importing text from google docs. I recorded VBA code to perform this operation. But when I run the code I get the error:

> Runtime error 4198 command failed.

How can I fix this?

```
Sub Macro2()
   '
   ' Macro2 Macro
   '
   Selection.InsertFile FileName:= _
      "https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/export?format=docx&id=blahblah" _
      , Range:="", ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 'selection.' so something needs to be selected before you run the macro